# What's The Best Logic For Sort an Array?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, logic

Let's Say We Have an Array Of Int :

```
int[] array = new int[5];
```

and inside of this array we have a 5 randomly numbers..

```
array = {10,5,7,0,3};
```

What Would be The Best Way To Change That array To This Array By Code

```
array[0]=0;
array[1]=3;
array[2]=5;
array[3]=7;
array[4]=10;
```

For Me i Thought about Creating Two Loops One Of i and One of j..

im gonna take the position 0 (i) and compare it with All the Other Numbers in The Array. i mean The positions j which is started from (i+1) till the end of the array (array.Length).

Then When i'll found that array[i] is Upper Than array[j] Simply i'll Change The first Value with The Other...

and Of course Here i need To Declare variable To Make That Change as shown :

```
int[] array = new int[5]{10,5,7,0,3};
int Change;
for(int i =0;i<array.Lenght;i++)  
{
    for(int j =i+1;j<array.Lenght;j++)  
     {
       if(array[i]>array[j])
        {
           change=array[i];
           array[i] = array[j];
           array[j] = change;
        }
    }
}
```

This is solve The Problem But even thought i don't Like That Logic || that Code

if you have another one Can You Tell Me About it ??

Comment: What's your definition of "best"? How do I know that one approach is better than another? And how do I know I have the best? How are you evaluating? What is it that you don't like about your current code?

Comment: You should find all you need here: https://www.youtube.com/user/AlgoRythmics

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Array.Sort` method.

```
int[] array = new int[5] { 10, 5, 7, 0, 3 };
Array.Sort(array);
```

On OP's request, I am providing the optimized code. Here complexity is O(Square(N)). I would  suggest you use merge sort or quick sort, these have complexity O(NLogN)

```
int[] array = new int[5] { 10, 5, 7, 0, 3 };
int change = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length - 2; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= array.Length - 2; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
        {
            change = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            array[j] = change;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You Killled My Logic sir hahah 
Thanks For Help i appreciate it

Comment: @ZakariaRedouane I have provided you one more solution, optimized your code, see it.

Comment: Oh Thanks That was a Good  Solution too

Comment: @ZakariaRedouane you should accept the answer if it has answered your question

Comment: In "if you have **another** one Can You Tell Me About it ??" pay attention to the word "another". OP did not ask for optimizing his code. Optimizing should be asked in Code Review.

Comment: I think you mean `O(NLogN)`, not `O(LogN)`.

Comment: Yes, so I have provided solution also. And it's our responsibility to provide the better code